# Is there an easier way to call a subclass's method on an ArrayList of both the subclass and superclass in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I have a class (let's call it Vehicle) and a subclass (Car). Instances of both are stored in one ArrayList. Car has a method that isn't inherited from vehicle, doStuff(). I want to doStuff() to every car in the ArrayList. This is the easiest solution I came up with:

```
vehicleList = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
            roster.add(new Vehicle());
            roster.add(new Car());

            for (Vehicle v: vehicleList){
                    if (v instanceof Car){
                            ((Car) v).doStuff();
                    }
            }
```

But I feel like there's a much simpler way to do it. So thanks in advance if you can offer a simpler solution.

Comment: There isn't. If `doStuff()` is only declared in `Car`, you'll need a `Car` reference to invoke it.

Comment: You could add `doStuff` as an abstract method of `Vehicle` I guess, if you were prepared to have `Vehicle` as an abstract class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list is declared as `List<Vehicle>`, then that's the right way to do it - you can't tell without checking if an individual item is a `Truck`, or a `Car`, or something else.

If it makes sense for `Vehicle` to have the method, you could declare `doStuff` there, and have it do nothing by default, and put a real implementation in `Car`. This is generally a sign of bad design though.

Another option would be to get a `List<Car>` instead, so you don't have to check each item in the list for it's type.  You could also put `doStuff` as part of an interface `CanDoStuff`, so it's not `Car` you're checking for - this way you can easily apply it to other classes as well.

Comment: So far this has been the most detailed and new answers haven't come in for a few minutes, so I'm marking yours as best. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" solution is to implement doStuff() in Vehicle, and have it do nothing.  e.g.

```
public void doStuff(args) { ; }
```

However, this is typically a hint of poor design.  Might be a good idea, might be bad.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Add `doStuff()` to `Vehicle` (default impl could be "do nothing")
2. Something along the lines of what you have. Some way of figuring out if a particular `Vehicle` can "do stuff". You could have a `canDoStuff()` method in the `Vehicle` class (still requires a cast and base class is starting to "know too much". You could have `Car` implement a `CanDoStuff` interface - works a bit better than using `Car` directly if you might one day have a `Van` which can doStuff too.

Answer (score 0):

Store like types together where ever possible. Then you wont have this problem. Ask yourself why you store all Vehicles in one list, if they all behave differently. The end. :)

You can do tricky things such as creating a "filtering iterator" which returns essentially a filtered sublist based on the class type. this is an advanced topic, but if your project has this list methodology quite prominent, you write that filter once and use it all over the place.